# Upgrade Issues on 18.04

Tags: networking

My Ubuntu 18.04 server was working great, it had two NICs, one connected to my LAN, the other a public internet facing one. It was running Apache2 and serving up websites without a problem both to the LAN and to the internet. It was running DNSMASQ for DNS and DHCP again without a problem. PCs connected to my LAN would be given an IP address and could access web pages via the server.

Then I did an upgrade to update the software.

It it no longer works. Well, I can no longer see webpages on the LAN PCs, or ping them (but it can resolve the name to an IP address). Strangely, typing a web address into a browser on a LAN PC sometimes takes me to one of the Apache pages instead.

IP forwarding is enabled (the net.ipv4.ip_forward is set).

Any ideas what I've done or what to check?

Comment: Look at your logs (/var/log/apt) and then you tell us what happened.

Comment: I can't see anything in there that'd help, but then I don't know what I'm looking for. There's no error messages. There's a warning about start and stop actions no longer beinging supprted.

Comment: OK, string from a fresh system, what are the steps to setting up IP forwarding (so the server acts like a router)?